# onclick do function and then click

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a button click, I want to trigger a click on another div that is doing some Ajax (backend logic) operation, **and then trigger the actual click** on the button.

I have tried the following with no success

```
$('#button').click(function(event) {
        $("#someDiv").click(); //at this point the ajax content will load..
        return true;
});
```

Comment: Why don't just doing the ajax inside your function ?

Comment: can you try `$( "#someDiv" ).trigger( "click" );` see if it helps

Comment: Do you wish to start the ajax request and then immediately process the original button click? Or do you wish to delay processing the rest of the original click handler till after the ajax request has successfully completed and returned a response? If the former, your code ought to work, I think. If the latter, you would need to rewrite your original click handler to pass the rest of its logic as a callback to the ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a boolean to save a state and fire the click on `#button` twice, executing the actual click only if the ajax has been loaded.
You can also disable the button when the ajax request is made.

```
var ajaxLoaded = false;

$('#button').click(function(event) {
    if (!ajaxLoaded){
        $('#button').prop('disabled', true);
        $("#someDiv").click();
        return false;
    }
    ajaxLoaded = false;
    $('#button').prop('disabled', false);
    return true;
});
```

And in the success callback of the ajax request,  update the value of `ajaxLoaded` and fire the click

```
ajaxLoaded = true;
$('#button').click();
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hacketo/9ksbgrzu/) (using setTimeout to simulate some async delay)

Comment: I just notice that the click event will always go first before the ajax call i tried many ways but your way is the only way so far.http://jsfiddle.net/50y212L4/4/

Comment: In your fiddle, `alert` block the request/success callback too. And as the alert is on the same stack that the listener, when alert is closed, it will continue execution instead of calling the success callback first

Comment: yes you are right i thought that if you put it first then i will be executed first that was my mistake.. i've learned something today. that the alert will go off first before ajax call. i think this is not the only exception am i right?

Comment: the ajax call is executed just before the `alert()` with `$("#click2").click()`, but the success callback will be called on another stack of execution so not before the first listener finish to execute. `alert` is something synchronously blocking like a `while(true)` that's why I never use it because sometime you do not understand fully the behaviour.

Comment: I see so the ajax was really called even before the `click` its just that the response of the ajax was a bit late due to the fact that it is executed lets say on a different line.. Am i correct?sorry i had to ask so i wont be doing the same mistake again in the future

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. The .click is a shortcut of .on(click), the listener, instead the trigger:

```
$('#button').click(function(event) {
        $("#someDiv").trigger( "click" ); //at this point the ajax content will load..
        return true;
});
```

Comment: You are wrong. [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) can also be used to trigger a click. Please refer to the documentation: "*This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler ) in the first two variations, **and .trigger( "click" ) in the third**.*"

Comment: You are right. If this don't work for the OP I delete the answer